# Codeigniter creating an ENUM field with dbforge

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, enums, dbforge

I create a ENUM field, here is my code:

```
$field['test'] = array(
  'type' => 'ENUM',
  'constraint' => array('a','b','c'),
  'default'=> "a"
);
$this->dbforge->add_field($field);
$this->dbforge->create_table('demo');
```

And I got a message:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ‘Array) DEFAULT ‘a’ NOT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
>   utf8_general_ci’ at line 2
>
> CREATE TABLE `ci_demo` ( `test` ENUM(Array) DEFAULT ‘a’ NOT NULL )
>   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this one

```
$field['test'] = array(
'type' => 'ENUM("a","b","c")',
'default' => 'a',
'null' => FALSE,
);
$this->dbforge->add_field($field);
$this->dbforge->create_table('demo');
```

[**Reference**](http://www.cecilieo.com/techblog/creating-a-simple-cron-job-with-codeigniter/)